# Why does Launchpad fail to find 'glib-compile-schemas' while building for PPA?

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly, launchpad

So, I'm trying to publish my app in my PPA, but I'm having problems related with building my app. Here you have the output:

```
/bin/sh: 1: glib-compile-schemas: not found
make[1]: *** [override_dh_install] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/build/buildd/virtuam-0.1ubuntu1'
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: /usr/bin/fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
******************************************************************************
Build finished at 20120709-2102
FAILED [dpkg-buildpackage died]
******************************************************************************
```

Even following the solutions posted in https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu, I have no luck. What should I do?

The build error is this: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/109704402/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.virtuam_0.1ubuntu1_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

Comment: It seems we were wrong to close this. On second look, it seems like a separate, not too localized problem with a perfectly good solution that will help others. I recommend we reopen this, and then make [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/204643/22949) a duplicate of *this*. Otherwise, people searching with this issue will be very confused when they get here and might not get an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your build dependencies are incomplete. From your build log I can see that it tries to install (upgrade) the `libglib2.0-0` package. However, `glib-compile-schemas` is provided by the `libglib2.0-bin` package which is not a dependency of `libglib2.0-0`.

To solve this, add `libglib2.0-dev` as build dependency which will install both `libglib2.0-bin` and `libglib2.0-0`.

Comment: OK, thanks... solved myself, but, as is the same solution, I give you the merit ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't specifying all of your build dependencies in the debian/control file.

Answer (score 1):

The missing dependency on libglib2.0-bin for glib-compile-schemas is actually a quickly bug. The fix is in precise-proposed. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu.