# Getting missing dependency for compilation glib-compile-schemas

Tags: gnome, make, makefile

I Downloaded empathy-3.0.1.tar.bz2 to install in **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS**.
I ran the makefile and I got the error :

> configure: error: glib-compile-schemas not found.

How can I fix this problem ? Please help me.

Comment: [probably related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161739/why-does-launchpad-fail-to-find-glib-compile-schemas-while-building-for-ppa)  if you find a suitable solution there, please post it as answer.

Comment: @cauon The solution [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/161739/why-does-launchpad-fail-to-find-glib-compile-schemas-while-building-for-ppa) should definitely work here too (and is equivalent to [this answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/234150/22949)). If you have a similar problem and that solution *didn't* work for you, I recommend [posting a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `glib-compile-schemas` is not available in any package for 10.04 LTS (Lucid). What I did to get around this, is to compile and install the latest glib manually, using: `./configure && make && make install`. I also needed to add `/usr/local/lib` to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 30):

You need the [header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_files). In Ubuntu and other Debian-based operating systems, header files are provided by `-dev` packages. So install [libglib2.0-dev [image: Install libglib2.0-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libglib2.0-dev), by clicking that link or by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Comment: this must be right answer

Comment: Please make this the accepted answer